# Text justification, removing unwanted move to next line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

I'm using sharelatex and I ran into some weird text justification
under the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Needed}
\cvdoubleitem{Familiar with}{C, C++, Assembly, Python, mySQL}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Nice to know}{Android, Neo4j, Redis, MongoDB}{}{}
\end{document}
```

This code produce the following, as you can see the mySQL and MongoDB
went to the next line.

[image: Unwanted behavior]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Well, command `\cvdoubleitem` is defined to add two items side by side. If you have only one item use command `\cvitem` instead.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{green}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.80]{geometry}
\name{John}{Doe} % <====================================================

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Needed}
\cvdoubleitem{Familiar with}{C, C++, Assembly, Python, mySQL}{}{}
\cvdoubleitem{Nice to know}{Android, Neo4j, Redis, MongoDB}{}{}
\cvitem{Familiar with}{C, C++, Assembly, Python, mySQL} % <=============
\cvitem{Nice to know}{Android, Neo4j, Redis, MongoDB} % <===============
\cvdoubleitem{Familiar with}{C, C++, Assembly, Python, mySQL}{Nice to know}{Android, Neo4j, Redis, MongoDB} % <================================
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]